# How to work with existing action Buttons

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal, action-button

I am receiving notifications from onesignal with actionButtons sent from the service. How can I deal with those buttons and handle their events?

```
    protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(final OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
            OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();

            // here I am getting the data sent thtough oneSignal
            final JSONObject additionalData = receivedResult.payload.additionalData;

            // here I am getting my buttons
            final List<OSNotificationPayload.ActionButton> actionButtons = receivedResult.payload.actionButtons;

            overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
            @Override
            public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
            try { 

            // Here I am creating my own button and adding it to the notification

            Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
            PendingIntent pendingIntentCall = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyService.this, 12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.phone_notif,getString(R.string.call),pendingIntentCall);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
          return builder;
         }
       };
     return true
  }
```

How can I handle event for the actionButtons that are received from one signal? They appear but when I click on them they act like if I am clicking on a notification ...

Answer (score 0):

OneSignal's Android SDK provides handlers for received notifications. You should set IDs for your buttons to distinguish one from another. You can also send additional data (e.g. url to visit or some other metadata) as a hash under `data` key. From their [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationopenedhandler-):

```
class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
  // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
  @Override
  public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
    OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
    JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
    String customKey;

    if (data != null) {
      customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
      if (customKey != null)
        Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
    }

    if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
      Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

    // The following can be used to open an Activity of your choice.
    // Replace - getApplicationContext() - with any Android Context.
    // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
    // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    // startActivity(intent);

     // Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml to prevent the launching of your main Activity
     //   if you are calling startActivity above.
     /* 
        <application ...>
          <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
        </application>
     /*
  }
}
```